# is there any problem with android jetpack compose UI because it is going back to previous changes?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am new in jetpack compose. i created some apps for practice but whenever i update my UI and run immediately it is working fine but after 1 or 2 hours it is going automatically to it's previous changes. for example, i have 1 button in my activity and i added another button in activity if i run app immediately it is showing both button but if i run same app after 1 hour than newly added button will be gone this is happening with all new UI changes.

As beginner in compose I don't know what to do and i couldn't find any solution. let'e me know it it is bug or am i missing something.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: provide more context about your code.

Comment: I have same issue also the OP describes, sometimes building the app will result in displaying an old version I started the development session with but will be resolved by the next run. It's not about the particular code and even so you can find my open source Compose project in GitHub. If this isn't a common experience I guess something is wrong with my setup and perhaps reinstalling Android Studio will fix the issues but I think there should be some easier fix also.